# Deleting non matching records from a table prior to linking

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in a new database containing data migrated from an old database.  These two tables need to be linked, but prior to that I need to remove those records that don't have matching id's.

The two tables in question are illustrated below;

[image]

I need to eradicate those rows in the landingDetails table that do not have corresponding landing headers in the landingHeaders table.  Can anyone suggest the correct form that a sql statement to carry this out should take.

By way of additional info.  When this is achieved it is my intention to link landing details to landing headers.  Currently there are approximately 107,000 rows in landing details and approxametly 8,500 rows in landing headers.

Thanks for any suggestions that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first major step is to backup your database :)

And give a try this query,

```
DELETE FROM LandingDetails WHERE LandingId NOT IN (SELECT LandingId FROM LandingHeaders)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  And your comment about ensuring that a backup exists first is very apposite (I have several !).